# Android Studio Virtual Device install stuck at - Invoking Installer Running Intel® HAXM installer

Tags: android, intel, haxm

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnsOF.png)
I just installed Android studio and was going through the steps to create a new virtual device. I was asked to download a couple of things in the same wizard which I selected and clicked on Accept. This install has been going on for a long time but does not get completed..could there be any reason for this? What can I do?

Comment: Thanks Akash, but it's been going on for about 2 hours now..is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Intel HAXM can be installed either through the Android* SDK Manager (recommended), or manually, by downloading the installer from Intel’s website.
please follow the instructions [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) to download Intel HAXM for your android studio.
Direct Download from [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) download the zip then extract it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes issue occur through android studio to install HAXM.

So you can directly download HAXM from Intent site 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm
 here according to your plateform. ex Windows.

Extract this and run intelhaxm-android.exe with adminstator.

If you still get issue with that then you can check here for troubleshoot.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Intel virtualisation (VT-x) enabled in your BIOS before you install HAXM.